# Loop through and compare

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, foreach

I have this code here the product tags can be animals, life or market. What I am trying to do is separate their list, but this code creates a new `ul` for every tag after animals and I do not know why, can anyone help?:

```
<?php

$versionvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag');

if($versionvalues){
        $previousTag = 'animals';
        foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) { 

                $currentTag = $versionvalue->name;


                if($currentTag != $previousTag){

                        echo '</ul><ul class="products" style="text-align:center;">';
                        $previousTag = $currentTag;
                }else{
                        $previousTag = $currentTag;
                }



       } 
}

?>
```

Maybe wordpress doesn't allow me to put get_the_terms values into a variable. I did an echo of the $previousTag in the loop is keeps returning animals.

I have realized that is code is inside my woocommerce loop for my products, so `$versionvales` gets updated for each product and `$previousTag` will also reset to animals for each product.

Comment: because you define `$previousTag` in the beginnig of the loop. move it out of it

Comment: Still seeing the same issue even with $previousTag defined outside of foreach

Comment: Since you update the question, apparently your code is not inside `the_loop()`

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying Raptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `$previousTag = 'animals'` before entering the `foreach` loop, otherwise it will be reinitialized to equal 'animals' at the start of each iteration:

```
if($versionvalues){ 
        $previousTag = 'animals';
        foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) { 

         .....

        }
}
```

Comment: Still seeing the same issue even with $previousTag defined outside of foreach

Answer (score 0):

You reinitialized the `$previousTag` in each loop.

```
<?php
$versionvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag');
if($versionvalues){ 
  $previousTag = 'animals';
  foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) { 
    $currentTag = $versionvalue->name;
    if($currentTag != $previousTag){
      echo '</ul><ul class="products" style="text-align:center;">';
      $previousTag = $currentTag;
    } else {
      $previousTag = $currentTag;
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Still seeing the same issue even with $previousTag defined outside of foreach

Answer (score 0):

just do not overwrite the variable each time

```
$versionvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag');

if($versionvalues){ 
                $previousTag = 'animals';
        foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) { 

                $currentTag = $versionvalue->name;


                if($currentTag != $previousTag){

                        echo '</ul><ul class="products" style="text-align:center;">';
                        $previousTag = $currentTag;
                }else{
                        $previousTag = $currentTag;
                }



       } 
}

?>
```

Comment: Still seeing the same issue even with $previousTag defined outside of foreach